# how to compute P(X>x) while x goes to infinity

Tags: probability

Can you help with this kind of question?  It goes to infinity.

---

Suppose X is a discrete random variable defined on the points x = 0, 1, 2, 3, ....

Compute

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty P(X>x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$P(X>n)=P(X=n+1)+P(X=n+2)+\cdots$$If you do that substitution for every term in your sum, how many times does $P(X=0)$ appear? What about $P(X=1)$ or $P(X=2)$? Can you rearrange this into a sum you recognise?

Comment: I did it like that before writing here. I think P(X=0) will be 1

Comment: ops I mean P(X=0) will be zero

Comment: Exactly, so we have $0\cdot P(X=0)$. How many do we have of $P(X=1)$?

Comment: 1⋅P(X=1) + 2 ⋅ P(X=2) + P ⋅ (X=3) + n ⋅ P(X=n)

Comment: At the end I got  n⋅P(X=n) ? 
Am I Right?

Comment: Yes. So in the end, $\sum P(X>n)=\sum nP(X=n)$. Do you recognise that last sum?